# Frequent Corrupt Indexes in MySQL 5.6. Is this a MySQL bug?

Tags: mysql, innodb, corruption

I´m having problems with mysql indexes with INNODB getting corrupted. Initially I solved it by rebuilding the tables but now the tables are to large to rebuild, and i´m tired of mysql not showing consistent results.

I´m inserting close to 10000 records daily among 4 or 5 tables, and I have some jobs continuously updating data on those records (probably 100000 updates a day)

Is this a bug in MySQL? How would you solve this issue?

In the following statements you can see the discrepancy because the row with 3 conditions shows 3433 results and if I remove one condition I get 0 results. I use the UNION to show that the queries are done almost at the same time so it´s very unlikely that the records are actually disappearing between the queries and coming back right after, because when I repeat the query I get the same results.

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM licitaciones WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7 and tipo_id > 0                                                                                              
       UNION 
       SELECT count(*) FROM licitaciones WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7;                                                                                                       
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                     
| count(*) |                                                                                                                                                                                     
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                     
|     3433 |                                                                                                                                                                                     
|        0 |                                                                                                                                                                                     
+----------+                                                                                                                                                                                     
2 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

Here is the mysql version... I´m using INNODB by the way.

```
mysql> select version();                                                                                                                                                                         
+-------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                      
| version()               |                                                                                                                                                                      
+-------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                      
| 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |                                                                                                                                                                      
+-------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                      
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just to clarify. The UNION was only to expose the fact that the rows were not changing from one statement to the other, but the result is the same if the queries are performed in separate statements:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM licitaciones WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7 and tipo_id > 0;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     3436 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.55 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM licitaciones WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

MORE INFO:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM licitaciones WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7 and tipo_id > 0;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type        | possible_keys                | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | licitaciones | index_merge | entidad_id,tipo_id,estado_id | entidad_id,estado_id | 5,4     | NULL | 3557 | Using intersect(entidad_id,estado_id); Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM licitaciones WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type        | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | licitaciones | index_merge | entidad_id,estado_id | entidad_id,estado_id | 5,4     | NULL | 3557 | Using intersect(entidad_id,estado_id); Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> show create table licitaciones;
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| licitaciones | CREATE TABLE `licitaciones` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `detected` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `num_constancia` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fila` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_proceso` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entidad_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `objeto` longtext,
  `cuantia` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_fecha_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_updated` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_json` mediumtext,
  `fastcodes` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `num_constancia` (`num_constancia`),
  KEY `entidad_id` (`entidad_id`),
  KEY `tipo_id` (`tipo_id`),
  KEY `estado_id` (`estado_id`),
  KEY `tipo_fecha_id` (`tipo_fecha_id`),
  KEY `fecha` (`fecha`),
  KEY `cuantia` (`cuantia`),
  KEY `num_proceso` (`num_proceso`),
  KEY `extra_updated` (`extra_updated`),
  KEY `detected` (`detected`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltextidx` (`objeto`,`fastcodes`,`extra_json`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32050336 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you please run the individual queries with EXPLAIN and show which index each is using? Obviously it shouldn't matter which index it's using or if it is using no index. But it would tell you which index, if any, may be corrupt. Then you could drop that index and perhaps recreate it without rebuilding the whole table.

Comment: And please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE licitaciones` so we can see what indexes you have in this table.

Comment: Ok, just added the extra info...

Answer (score 2):

The Rick James's answer is right, I just could not add a comment.

We got a very similar problem, the query with special conditions can not find the record, but that record is here by other where conditions. The problem is the "index_merge", it solved by avoiding the "index_merge_intersection":

```
SET SESSION optimizer_switch='index_merge_intersection=off';
```

or

```
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='index_merge=off';
```

It also worked by adding or removing some indexes to avoid the "index_merge".

Answer (score 0):

The index is *not corrupt*.

There is nothing controlling the order of the rows.  In fact, if the two counts had been the same you would have gotten only one row of output -- because `UNION` means `UNION DISTINCT`.

Do the query this way instead:

```
SELECT "with tipo" As the_case,
       count(*)
    FROM licitaciones
    WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7 and tipo_id > 0
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT "without",
       count(*)
    FROM licitaciones
    WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7;
```

Better yet, do both in a single `SELECT`:

```
SELECT count(*)         AS "without tipo test",
       SUM(tipo_id > 0) AS "with tipo test"
    FROM licitaciones
    WHERE entidad_id = 103 AND estado_id = 7;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but the union has nothing to do with te problem. The result is the same if I perform the queries in separate statements.

Comment: But thanks for pointing the fact that people may thin that´s the problem. I added an explanation about that in the question...

Comment: The single-query version should not have a condition in the WHERE clause for `tipo_id > 0` if you want to count all rows.

Comment: @jacmkno - Which version of 5.6 are you running?  And, is it Oracle's not Percona's?

Comment: I installed this version with apt-get install mysql-server-5.6. select @@version_comment shows "(Ubuntu)" so it should by Oracle´s version (I think) as pointed by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317869/determine-if-mysql-or-percona-or-mariadb.

Comment: A longer answer on how to determine the Oracle/Percona/MariaDB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611296/how-can-i-detect-whether-connected-database-is-mariadb-or-mysql/43692813#43692813

Comment: That would mean it´s Oracle´s MySQL: "Oracle's MySQL starts with N.N.N, but might continue with -enterprise (paid version), -community (free version), -0ubuntu0 (ported by Ubuntu), -Debian, etc."

Comment: @jacmkno - that seems to be the case.  Meanwhile Percona says N.N.N-N.N, as if the extra numbers are their internal releases (after re-applying fixes to Oracle's base code).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating with the EXPLAIN and SHOW CREATE TABLE output.

It appears you have only single-column indexes, and MySQL is trying to use the [index-merge optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html) to make use of more than one index. Index-merge is not a well-tested feature of MySQL.

I can't find a reference to a bug regarding index-merge except some that involve partitioned tables. But it's possible a bug exists that have not been reported.

I would suggest that you learn how to use multi-column indexes instead of relying on the index-merge feature. It'll be more reliable, and probably have much better performance too.

This index should help both your queries:

```
ALTER TABLE licitaciones ADD KEY (entidad_id, estado_id, tipo_id);
```

Read my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). Watch the video of me presenting this talk here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: I´ll give it a try and update the correct answer if it works, but I´m afraid I need a multicolumn index starting with each column and including every column because those columns are exposed filters... That´s probably going to take a lot of disk space which I don´t have... Thanks for the tip about the single-field index combination feature (index-merging) not being trustworthy in MySQL, do you know if it can be trusted in any other DB engine like PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm not an expert with PostgreSQL optimization, but the manual has some information about it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html But I don't know if it's buggy or not.